# C - memset vs free

Tags: c, free, memset

I am confused on what actually happens in memory when memset is called versus what happens when you call free.

For example I have a pointer A that points to an array of char*'s

```
char** A = (char**)calloc(5, sizeof(char*));
int i;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  //filling
  A[i] = (char*)calloc(30, sizeof(char)); 
  scanf("%s", &A[i]);
}
```

now I want to reset it my char** pointer and all the elements
it points to be completely empty

```
memset(A, 0, 5);
```

or

```
free(A);
```

what is the difference?

I am somewhat new to C so please speak in layman's terms thank you

Answer (score 12):

The difference is that `memset` actually sets the value of a block of memory, while `free` returns the memory for use by the operating system.

By analogy using physical things, `memset(beer, 0, 6)` applied to a six-pack of beer would apply the value of '0' to all six members of the array `beer`, while `free(beer)` would be the equivalent of giving the six-pack away to a friend.

Comment: Good answer. I can add that, while operating systems implement this differently, it might at least help to imagine the operating system as holding a series of pointers to blocks of memory, and when you use a malloc(or similar), the OS returns a pointer to that memory block, and marks it as "in use" internally, as to avoid assigning the same block to someone else while its in use. When you call free, you're telling the operating system to unset the "in use" flag for that block. Failing to call free when you're done with the data, leads to a full memory after a while - memory leak

Comment: It *might* return the memory to the operating system or hold on to it to satisfy further requests of memory faster (the norm). In the first case, dereferencing the pointer again will likely result in an access violation, in the second it is far more likely to lead to silent corruption of program state.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I said it's good to imagine it this way for educational purposes. In general too though, after calling free, it's best to assume it's passed on to the operating system right away..since you can't know when, assume the worst

Answer (score 7):

The [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) function sets an area of memory to the requested value. Do note that the size you provide is the number of *bytes*.

The [`free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) function releases the allocated memory so it can't be used anymore. Calling `free` doesn't usually modify the memory in any way. Using the memory after calling `free` leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 3):

Both approaches are incorrect, but somewhat complementary.

`memset` will set the content of the buffer to the given value, 0 in your case. This will change the value of the pointers, which will cause you to lose the references to the allocated buffers (in each `A[i]`).

`free(A)` will release the buffer pointed by A, but this buffer contains pointers, and each of the buffers that is pointed by them will not be freed.

in short - memset does not free a dynamically allocated buffer, and free does not set it to zero.

A correct approach will be something like that:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    // complementary to
    // A[i] = (char*)calloc(30, sizeof(char)); 
    free(A[i]);
}
// complementary to
// char** A = (char**)calloc(5, sizeof(char*));
free(A);
A = NULL; // so no one gets confused...
```

Comment: Perhaps add a note that all-bits-zero need not be a`NULL`-pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`free` deallocates the memory, which means A would still be pointing to the same memory location, which is invalid now.

`memset` will set the memory currently pointed to by A, to whatever you want.

Comment: “A would still be pointing” -> No. `A` and all other pointers to the freed memory become indeterminate when `free(A)` is invoked. If they did not become indeterminate, the program in http://trust-in-soft.com/dangling-pointer-indeterminate/ would not print “0x7fffb4e003bf is different from 0x7fffb4e003bf”.

Answer (score 0):

`memset` changes the contents at the memory address. It does not alter whether the memory is allocated/deallocated.

`free` does not change the contents at the memory address. It deallocates the block of memory which makes it available for the program to reclaim and reuse. Therefore any pointers to this block become invalid and trying to access the memory should result in a Segfault ("if you're lucky" as my professor would say).

Use `memset` when you know you are going to be accessing the data at that address again. Use `free` when you know that the data will no longer be accessed ever again and that the program may reclaim that memory.

Answer (score 0):

memset() method just replaces the x memory bytes with a given character the allocated memory which is pointed by a pointer *a;

```
memset(a, 'a', x);
```

The prototype of memset() method is:

```
void* memset(void*, unsigned int, int);
```

`memset()` behaves like `strcpy()` but the difference is that `memcpy()` copied the data as it is (byte), but `strcpy` copies the formatted string as well (so takes more time than `memcpy` to execute).

However, `free()` method just deallocates the memory space and makes it available to get occupied.

Answer (score 0):

While other answers explain the difference, let me add an example when both memset() and free() will need to be used together, in a specific order:

If the malloc'ed memory region was used to store any critical/valuable information that needs to be erased to prevent others from snooping on it (say some security-related stuff like managing a password or some other crypto), you would want to first erase the contents in that memory region and then call free() on it to give away that region's control back to the OS.

Hence, just like free() is the opposite of malloc(), memset(to zero)-then-free() is the opposite of calloc().